# Determining a formula to approximate a periodic error

Tags: trigonometry, approximation

I am working on a barn door tracker for taking astro photos.  My drive train has a small periodic error that I'm trying to eliminate and I was hoping someone might be able to suggest a formula that would approximate what is shown in the attached image.  The image shows three cycles of the error.  It appears to me to be similar to a sine wave but with the upper half stretched out.  It doesn't need to be exact, just something so when I subtract it out, I'll get close to a straight line.  I hope that makes sense.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

[image: periodic error]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a **curtate cycloid**:$C(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ where

$$  \begin{matrix}x = At-B\sin(t)\\ y = A-B\cos(t) \end{matrix}$$

for $0 < A < B$. I made the following with $A=1$, $B=4$.

[image]

To choose different values of $A,B$ and see what happens, see: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4jl1c70nsa

The following was taken from Wolfram Mathworld:

[image]